# Properties of Minkowski product of sets

Tags: general-topology

We work in a normed vector space $\mathbb{X}$. Let $A$ a subset of unit sphere $\mathbb{S}_1=\{ x\in \mathbb{X} \mid \|x\|= 1 \}$. Decide if:

- $A$ is compact iff $[0,1]A=\{ tx  | x\in A, t\in [0,1] \}$ is compact. If not, find an example.
- $A$ is closed iff $[0,1]A$ is closed. If not, find an example.

My workbook is Introductory Topology:Exercises and Solutions, by Mohammed Hichem Mortad and, using the definition from the beggining of the chapter 3, I did not find anything.

For the second one, I tried to use sequences. Suppose that $A$ is closed, then it follows that $x\in A$. Letting $(y_n)\in [0,1]A$, there is $(t_n)\rightarrow t\in [0,1]$ and $(x_n)\rightarrow x\in A$ such that $$
y_n=x_nt_n\rightarrow xt\in [0,1]A .$$
So, $[0,1]A$ is closed. The converse is unclear for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that $A=f^{-1}(1)$ where $f:[0,1]A\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(v)=\lVert v\rVert$. Therefore $A$ is always closed in $[0,1]A$ but not necessarily in $\mathbb{X}$.

- If $A$ is compact then so is $[0,1]\times A$ and thus $[0,1]A$ being a continuous image of $[0,1]\times A$ via $(t,x)\mapsto tx$.
- If $[0,1]A$ is compact then $A=f^{-1}(1)$ is closed in $[0,1]A$ and thus it is compact as a closed subset of compact space.
- Now you've almost solved "$A$ closed $\Rightarrow$ $[0,1]A$ closed" implication. So you start with convergent $(y_n)\subseteq [0,1]A$ and you realize that $y_n=t_nx_n$ for some $(t_n)\subseteq [0,1]$ and $(x_n)\subseteq A$. However neither $(t_n)$ nor $(x_n)$ sequences have to be convergent! But $[0,1]$ is compact and so $(t_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, say $(t_{n_k})$. If $t_{n_k}\to 0$ then obviously $y_{n_k}\to 0$ and so $y_n\to 0$ by the limit uniqueness. Note that $0\in[0,1]A$ and so we can assume that $t_{n_k}\to t\neq 0$. And with that we can assume that $t_{n_k}\neq 0$ for any $k$. Therefore $x_{n_k}=(1/t_{n_k})y_{n_k}$ makes sense and it has to be convergent as a product of convergent sequences (scalar multiplication is continuous). And since $A$ is closed it has to converg to some $x\in A$. It follows that $y_{n_k}=t_{n_k}x_{n_k}$ converges to $tx\in[0,1]A$ and so does $y_n$ by the limit uniqueness.
- The last implication, i.e. "$[0,1]A$ closed $\Rightarrow$ $A$ closed" follows from my initial observation that $A$ is always closed in $[0,1]A$ and the fact that "being closed in" is a transitive relation.